# Zoom integration Invalid access token. with Php

Tags: php, zoom-sdk

I am trying to integrate Zoom via OAuth
with PHP

to generate Zoom meeting

and this is the code i have trying

```
private function auth_token()
{
    $client = new Client();

    //====== get Auth token =======
    $response = $client->post('https://zoom.us/oauth/token', [
        'form_params' => [
            'grant_type' => 'client_credentials',
            'client_id' => $this->apiKey,
            'client_secret' => $this->apiSecret,
        ],
    ]);
    $accessToken = json_decode($response->getBody())?->access_token ;

    return $accessToken;
}
```

and the token is get properly

then

```
public function create_meeting()
{
    try {
        $accessToken = $this->auth_token();

        $client = new Client();

        $response = $client->post('https://api.zoom.us/v2/users/me/meetings', [
            'form_params' => [
                'topic' => 'Your Meeting Topic',
                'type' => 2, // Scheduled Meeting
            ],
            'headers' => [
                'Authorization' => "Bearer $accessToken",
            ],
        ]);

        $responseData = json_decode($response->getBody(), true);

        echo 'Meeting created: ' . print_r($responseData, true) . PHP_EOL;
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        echo 'Error creating meeting: ' . $e->getMessage() . PHP_EOL;
    }
}
```

the problem is I get an error

```
{
  "code": 124,
  "message": "Invalid access token."
}
```

how can I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

Zoom Developer Advocate here. Currently Zoom OAuth only offers the `client_credentials` grant type for [Zoom Team Chat REST API endpoints](https://developers.zoom.us/docs/api/rest/reference/chatbot/methods/#operation/sendChatbot).

You will have to use the `account_credentials` grant type instead and [add the account_id property](https://developers.zoom.us/docs/internal-apps/s2s-oauth/#to-generate-an-access-token).

```php
private function auth_token()
{
    $client = new Client();

    //====== get Auth token =======
    $response = $client->post('https://zoom.us/oauth/token', [
        'form_params' => [
            'grant_type' => 'account_credentials',
            'account_id' => ACCOUNT_ID,
            'client_id' => $this->apiKey,
            'client_secret' => $this->apiSecret,
        ],
    ]);
    $accessToken = json_decode($response->getBody())?->access_token ;

    return $accessToken;
}
```

You can find your `account_id` value on your [Server to Server App type](https://developers.zoom.us/docs/internal-apps/) build flow page.

[image]

For questions specific to the Zoom Developer Platform, feel free to ask on the [Zoom devforum](https://devforum.zoom.us/).